# How to tweet from GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter

I want to be able to Tweet from my app running on GAE.

Please suggest some Python library or HTTP API for the purpose.

Comment: why don't you google "twitter python api"? The first answer is http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

Comment: Is this library compatible with GAE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project worked for me: https://github.com/tav/tweetapp/blob/master/standalone/twitter_oauth_handler.py
It's only one file so it's easy to get it started and uses OAuth for authentication with twitter.

Answer (score 1):

**About python-twitter**: I think you can use this lib it seems to be compatible with GAE: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/twitter.py

Also:

Twitter has a very great REST API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api, You  can also to simply use urlfetch and simplejson from appengine.

For authentication Twitter uses OAuth and recommend to understand how it work:

> Twitter supports a few authentication methods and with a range of
>   OAuth authentication styles you may be wondering which method you
>   should be using. When choosing which authentication method to use you
>   should understand the way that method will affect your users
>   experience and the way you write your application.

Twitter share a very great how to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

You can also see the part of code: http://code.google.com/p/jaikuengine/source/browse/trunk/oauth_client.py from jaikuengine.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [**twython**](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) in the past. I can't remember what made me select it over other libraries but I was using it on GAE and it is kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [Tweet Engine](https://github.com/arachnid/tweetengine) project of interest. It demonstrates quite simply how to use the Twitter REST API from App Engine.